# Is it possible to link a certificate to specific device in client certificate authentication?

Tags: authentication, iis, certificate, pki

Need to authenticate a server using certificate, I have used OpenSSL to generate certificate and it was able to authenticate with certificate by enabling client certificate authentication in IIS.

Now when I export the certificate from the device and tried to install it in the other device it was able to authenticate the server, is there any possible way to link or generate a certificate that will only work for the specific machine?

Comment: "Now when I export the certificate from the device and tried to install it in the other device it was able to authenticate the server" is the original problem you should try to resolve. Certificates can be installed in a way that you cannot export them out (at least for Windows). This is something you should try to enforce on client side. IIS does not provide you a way to do that on server side.

Comment: It needs both the public and private keys for an SSL Certificate to function: https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-support/certificate-pfx-file-export-import-iis-10.htm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - keep the private key *private*.

Moving a certificate by itself to another client won't let you authenticate as the owner of that certificate.  You would have to move both the certificate and its corresponding private key.

There are generally two ways you can stop the private key being copied:

1. Use administrative controls to ensure nobody in your organisation copies the keys.  This is usually in the form of an agreement between the certificate issuer and the entity named in the certificate, to the effect that "you shall not copy the private key!!".  As you can imagine, depending on the scenario, this might not be that enforceable.
2. If the certificate is certifying a device, generate and store the private key in a hardware device that is a permanent fixture in that client device.  A [Trusted Platform Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) is an example of a device fitted in most modern end-user devices for this purpose.
3. If the certificate is certifying a person, generate and store the private key in a hardware device that is issued to that person.  A smart-card is an example of such a device.  You would probably also need administrative controls here to ensure that the user doesn't share their card with others and that they keep any PINs or other authentication data private.

Note that attempting to certify something like the DNS name of the client device as as unique identifier doesn't work, as DNS, MAC addresses etc. can be spoofed.